# C#: 'A change set cannot include changes to more than '1' source resources' when adding a user To Group using Azure Graph API 2.0

Tags: c#, exception, azure, active-directory

I am trying to add a user to group using Azure GraphClient API 2.0 (2.0.5, latest as of 2/9/2015) and having following exceptions:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"**A change set cannot include changes to more than '1' source resources.**"},"values":null}}

with the code snippet below:

```
IUser userToAdd = GetUserByObjectId('user_object_id');
Group groupToUpdate = GetGroupByObjectId('group_object_id') as Group;

if (userToAdd != null && groupToUpdate != null)
{
    groupToUpdate.Members.Add(userToAdd as DirectoryObject);
    groupToUpdate.UpdateAsync().Wait(); <---------- Exception thrown at this point
}
```

What I have done so far:
1. Tested so that an exception will not be thrown if I comment out 'groupToUpdate.Members.Add'
2. I looked up the error message 'A change set cannot include changes to more than '1' source resources' but wasn't able to find any references.
3. Checked Add Member To Group example from https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet to make sure I am not doing it wrongly.
4. I confirmed that all other operations such as CRUD user, Create Group, Delete Group, Search and look up functions are working fine.

Any help would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE (2/10/2015):**

I have captured Fiddler Trace Log.

Sequence of requests:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
9   201 HTTPS   graph.windows.net   /%TENANT_ID%/groups?api-version=1.5 576 no-cache; Expires: -1   application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8 w3wp:2280           
10  200 HTTPS   graph.windows.net   /%TENANT_ID%/groups?api-version=1.5 13,242  no-cache; Expires: -1   application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8 w3wp:2280           
11  200 HTTPS   graph.windows.net   /%TENANT_ID%/groups/%GROUP_ID%?api-version=1.5  576 no-cache; Expires: -1   application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8 w3wp:2280           
12  200 HTTPS   graph.windows.net   /%TENANT_ID%/users/%USER_ID%?api-version=1.5    1,083   no-cache; Expires: -1   application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8 w3wp:2280           
13  400 HTTPS   graph.windows.net   /%TENANT_ID%/directoryObjects/%GROUP_ID%/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group/members?api-version=1.5  164 private application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;charset=utf-8    w3wp:2280           
14  204 HTTPS   graph.windows.net   /%TENANT_ID%/directoryObjects/%GROUP_ID%/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group?api-version=1.5  0   no-cache; Expires: -1       w3wp:2280
```

Each Request Detail:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/groups?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceUrlConventions: KeyAsSegment
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Authorization: %ACCESS_TOKEN%
X-ClientService-ClientTag: Office 365 API Tools 1.1.0612
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Length: 191
Expect: 100-continue

{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","description":"test@%DOMAIN%","displayName":"TESTGROUP","mailEnabled":false,"mailNickname":"nickname","securityEnabled":true}
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/directoryObjects/%GROUP_ID%/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: %SOME_KEY_1%
request-id: 6a690e15-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-35d52ebd5050
client-request-id: e537b83b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bc80c5025c71
x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
ocp-aad-session-key: %KEY%
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 22:19:31 GMT
Content-Length: 576

{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group/@Element","odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"%GROUP_ID%","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"test@%DOMAIN%","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"TESTGROUP","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"%MAIL_NICKNAME%","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true}

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/groups?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceUrlConventions: KeyAsSegment
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Authorization: %ACCESS_TOKEN%
X-ClientService-ClientTag: Office 365 API Tools 1.1.0612
Host: graph.windows.net


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: %SOME_KEY_1%
request-id: d74a33fb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-43e3e5c5a35f
client-request-id: 1d53a420-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-151596872026
x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
ocp-aad-session-key: %KEY%
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 22:19:33 GMT
Content-Length: 13242

{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","value":[{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"%GROUP_ID%","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"test@%DOMAIN%","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"TESTGROUP","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"%MAIL_NICKNAME%","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"0c27bdbc-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-66fd5f63d798","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"ADSyncPasswordSet","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"ADSyncPasswordSet","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"0cc118be-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b624ae770d19","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"DNS clients who are permitted to perform dynamic updates on behalf of some other clients (such as DHCP servers).","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"DnsUpdateProxy","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"DnsUpdateProxy","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"14072b09-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e537635d34c0","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"DNS clients who are permitted to perform dynamic updates on behalf of some other clients (such as DHCP servers).","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"DnsUpdateProxy","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"DnsUpdateProxy","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"19f93a9d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b91ece8b24f9","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"FIMSyncOperators","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"FIMSyncOperators","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"1f75b1c0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e550328f8973","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members of this group can access WMI resources over management protocols (such as WS-Management via the Windows Remote Management service). This applies only to WMI namespaces that grant access to the user.","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"413668fe-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a0ebcf476dfc","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"ADSyncBrowse","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"ADSyncBrowse","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-1112","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"4be872db-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2eb7079a44ed","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"HelpLibraryUpdaters","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"HelpLibraryUpdaters","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"6cebb7a3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f3cc66597c7f","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"DNS Administrators Group","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"DnsAdmins","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"DnsAdmins","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"6d5e8c74-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e74dad7e6fd9","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members in the group have the required access and privileges to be assigned as the log on account for the associated instance of SQL Server Browser.","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$%DOMAIN%","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser_%DOMAIN%","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"6ff48cbf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2be51fd0f1bb","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"FIMSyncAdmins","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"FIMSyncAdmins","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"8f19946b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8fe4448340e8","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members in the group have the required access and privileges to be assigned as the log on account for the associated instance of SQL Server Browser.","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"9fa2e738-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-009211a5a4db","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members of this group can access WMI resources over management protocols (such as WS-Management via the Windows Remote Management service). This applies only to WMI namespaces that grant access to the user.","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"b30426e5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e7c1074d121e","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"FIMSyncBrowse","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"FIMSyncBrowse","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"b351bd7f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d7cc91852941","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"FIMSyncPasswordSet","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"FIMSyncPasswordSet","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"b8c3e590-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-82c3ad150d79","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members in the group have the required access and privileges to be assigned as the log on account for the associated instance of SQL Server Active Directory Helper in SQL Server 2008.","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"ba74d1e1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ba7733c5f248","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"FIMSyncJoiners","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"FIMSyncJoiners","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1619918607-3034894204-2710842436-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"c302433d-fa52-40fc-97bb-d4b17331db77","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Administrators for %DOMAIN%","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"%DOMAIN% Administrators","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"d9026cd3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f1b90bf7935c","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"c657ef3c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b9f48cf659da","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"DNS Administrators Group","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"DnsAdmins","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"DnsAdmins","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"cc4ec8c6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ab5a1b2ea5f3","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"Administrators","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"BposMailNickName","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"cda3c0e8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-964323393fe0","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members in the group have the required access and privileges to be assigned as the log on account for the associated instance of SQL Server Agent.","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"SQLServerSQLAgentUser$SQLEXPRESS","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"SQLServerSQLAgentUser_SQLEXPRESS","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"e29d60e1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c4c553ae802c","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"ADSyncAdmins","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"ADSyncAdmins","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"e69fa9da-a214-4e32-a1f3-8064e3413ffa","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":null,"dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"ADSyncOperators","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"ADSyncOperators","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"eca4dcea-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5bfdb52cc127","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"Members in the group have the required access and privileges to be assigned as the login account for the specified instance of SQL Server.","dirSyncEnabled":true,"displayName":"SQLServerMSSQLUser$SQLEXPRESS","lastDirSyncTime":"2014-12-19T03:38:25Z","mail":null,"mailNickname":"SQLServerMSSQLUser_SQLEXPRESS","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":"S-1-5-21-1993123774-3458547345-3703279742-xxxx","provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true},{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"f509a5a9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-eb6e6c4d1883","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"demo","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"demo","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"b5ecf2f6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0056132ccac4","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true}]}

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/groups/%GROUP_ID%?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceUrlConventions: KeyAsSegment
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Authorization: %ACCESS_TOKEN%
X-ClientService-ClientTag: Office 365 API Tools 1.1.0612
Host: graph.windows.net


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: %SOME_KEY_2%
request-id: 1ae63825-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-10135628a629
client-request-id: 6c971ab8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4a794cdf8fb9
x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
ocp-aad-session-key: %KEY%
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 22:19:34 GMT
Content-Length: 576

{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group/@Element","odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group","objectType":"Group","objectId":"%GROUP_ID%","deletionTimestamp":null,"description":"test@%DOMAIN%","dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"TESTGROUP","lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"%MAIL_NICKNAME%","mailEnabled":false,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"securityEnabled":true}

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/users/%USER_ID%?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceUrlConventions: KeyAsSegment
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Authorization: %ACCESS_TOKEN%
X-ClientService-ClientTag: Office 365 API Tools 1.1.0612
Host: graph.windows.net


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: %SOME_KEY_1%
request-id: 99314ed2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ee71fd4ffbfe
client-request-id: d6b9b8a2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-98ec20e65198
x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
ocp-aad-session-key: %KEY%
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 22:19:34 GMT
Content-Length: 1083

{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element","odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User","objectType":"User","objectId":"%USER_ID%","deletionTimestamp":null,"accountEnabled":true,"assignedLicenses":[],"assignedPlans":[],"city":null,"country":null,"department":null,"dirSyncEnabled":null,"displayName":"John Smith","facsimileTelephoneNumber":null,"givenName":"John","immutableId":null,"jobTitle":null,"lastDirSyncTime":null,"mail":null,"mailNickname":"%DOMAIN%ONMICROSOFT","mobile":null,"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,"otherMails":["jsmith@%DOMAIN%"],"passwordPolicies":null,"passwordProfile":null,"physicalDeliveryOfficeName":null,"postalCode":null,"preferredLanguage":"en-us","provisionedPlans":[],"provisioningErrors":[],"proxyAddresses":[],"sipProxyAddress":null,"state":null,"streetAddress":null,"surname":"Smith","telephoneNumber":null,"usageLocation":"US","userPrincipalName":"jsmith@%DOMAIN%.onmicrosoft.com","userType":"Member"}

------------------------------------------------------------------
POST https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/directoryObjects/%GROUP_ID%/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group/members?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceUrlConventions: KeyAsSegment
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Authorization: %ACCESS_TOKEN%
X-ClientService-ClientTag: Office 365 API Tools 1.1.0612
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Length: 49
Expect: 100-continue

{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"}
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: %SOME_KEY_1%
request-id: 856504e9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5bd2e6c64d44
client-request-id: a4ce7205-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-77fad62c00f7
x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
ocp-aad-session-key: %KEY%
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 22:19:34 GMT
Content-Length: 164

{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"A change set cannot include changes to more than '1' source resources."},"values":null}}

------------------------------------------------------------------
MERGE https://graph.windows.net/%TENANT_ID%/directoryObjects/%GROUP_ID%/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceUrlConventions: KeyAsSegment
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Authorization: %ACCESS_TOKEN%
X-ClientService-ClientTag: Office 365 API Tools 1.1.0612
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Length: 50
Expect: 100-continue

{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group"}
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: %SOME_KEY_2%
request-id: f05a4c03-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-fc245fd03452
client-request-id: f3627ada-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6c54958c5613
x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
ocp-aad-session-key: %KEY%
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 22:19:35 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATE (2/15/2015)
More code:

```
    private async Task<String> AcquireToken()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessToken))
        {
            throw new Exception("Authorization is Required.");
        }
        else
        {
            return AccessToken;
        }
    }

    private ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClient()
    {
        Uri baseServiceUri = new Uri('https://graph.windows.net');
        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(baseServiceUri , 'tenant_id'), async () => { return AccessToken; });
        return activeDirectoryClient;
    }

    private IUser GetUserByObjectId(String objectId)
    {
        try
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            return client.Users.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handling exceptions
        }
    }

    private IGroup GetGroupByObjectId(String objectId)
    {
        try
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            return client.Groups.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handling exceptions
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue.  We'll take a look and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Kyohei - are you queuing up any other batch requests before the call to UpdateAsync above?  Can you attach a fiddler trace please (and scrub out any passwords etc?

Comment: I am not using batch processes (i.e. ExecuteBatchAsync) and not queuing up any requests (i.e. defer flag) before the UpdateSync Call. I will capture the fiddler log and upload soon.

Comment: Dan - I have updated original post with Fiddler Trace Log. I am calling AddGroupAsync right before calling UpdateAsync code and UpdateAsync is to the newly created group entity.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very strange.  We're investigating further.

Comment: I could not repro this issue using our console app sample.  I did notice however that in your code snippet you are using an IGroup object, and groupToUpdate.Members does not expose the Add() method because it is a IPagedCollection.  If groupToUpdate were a Group object, groupToUpdate.Members does expose Add(), since this is an IList.  Can you try this again, but this time with the Group type please?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention 'as Group' in my code snippet but it is using Group object. I have updated code snippet to reflect that.

Comment: Kyohei - this is a total mystery on our side.  A couple of us have tried to repro your issue without success.  Is there any chance that you can provide us with more of your code sample in more detail please?  For example what do:  IUser userToAdd = GetUserByObjectId('user_object_id');
Group groupToUpdate = GetGroupByObjectId('group_object_id') as Group; do?

Comment: Dan - I have updated post with more code. In addition, I have constructor which stores value to AccessToken property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue though I don't know why it resolved it. What I did was to stop instantiating ActiveDirectoryClient object every time when I call GetUserByObjectId/GetGroupByObjectId. I cache it and reuse it, then I no longer getting the exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You used more than one instance of ActiveDirectoryClient. Using the same instance will fix the error.